# Divs over images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Say I have an image with a couple of dots in a web page. When someone clicks on the dots I want a JavaScript function to be executed and then a div placed over the clicked dot in the image. Something akin to markers in maps. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you open to solutions based around jQuery (or other) JavaScript frameworks? If so, do you have a preference (or are you already using one?)

Comment: Will prefer using jQuery as I am already familiar with the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start

```
<div id="map">
<ul>
 <li>marker</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm going to suggest jQuery in my answer.

```
$('#map li').each(function() {

   $(this).css({ cursor: 'pointer' }).click(function() {
        if (($this).find('.overlay').length > 0)) return;

        // figure out here where the contents for the div will come from. AJAX perhaps
        var contents = '<strong>hello</strong>';
        $(this).append('<div class="overlay">' + contents + '</div>');
   });

});
```

Position your dots with CSS. You'll probably want to give #map `position: relative` and then absolutely position your list items.

Then make some CSS for .overlay, so that it overlays correctly.